# What do we handle validation when using implicit setters and getters in CF9?

Tags: oop, validation, frameworks, coldfusion, cfc

How do we handle validation when using implicit setters and getters? I imagine when using explicit getters and setters, we would do something like:

```
public void function setFirstName() {
   if (! len(arguments.firstName)) {
      //throw some error/add an error to an error container
   } else {
      variables.firstName = arguments.firstName;
   }
}
```

If we use implicit getters and setters, we can define validation rules within the CFC itself, such as:

```
/**
* @validate string
* @validateparams {minLength=2, maxLength=40}
*/
property String firstName;
```

My questions are:

1. Would validation logic be in the CFC itself, or from the caller?
2. How do we trap errors and return them to the user for feedback? I can think of using try/catch, but should this be in the controller or the Model?

I'm a newbie to OOP and I've relied on [CFWheels](http://www.cfwheels.org) to do all of this for me. I'd like to learn how this functionality is handled in the absence of a framework, or if I were using Hibernate, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I was in college doing Java, validation was usually done in setter.  However, after working in web dev for a while, I noticed that it's generally not a good idea because you generally want to construct a batch of error messages and return to the user.  Therefore, a `validate()` method in the object, or a `validateX()` method at the Service layer that returns a collection of errors would be more suitable.

Having said that, beside ValidateThis, there's also http://hyrule.riaforge.org/ if you are running CF9.

Comment: thanks! Interesting stuff. I spent a few days reading and learnt a few things. Can you share any personal experiences working with validateThis or Hyrule? Hyrule looks really good to me!

Comment: I haven't used neither myself yet, but here's a presentation on ValidateThis http://experts.adobeconnect.com/p34432670/

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I do not think validation should be done inside the object that is being validated. I prefer an external process, such as ValidateThis http://www.validatethis.org/

It is a pretty powerful and flexible 'framework' (for lack of a beter word) for validating objects.  it allows you to validate properties that are simple values, complex values (structs, arrays) and other objects.

Comment: how would you tie validateThis into your model? Assuming you're using Hibernate: Would you call validateThis() from your controller before sending the data to the Model?

Comment: I would call validateThis in my service layer.

I have adopted a practice where when you call widgetService.saveWidget( widget ), it would fire the validation and if valid, save the object. If its not valid, it returns an object with the error messages.

The call to this service method would be in my controller.